# Retrieve many through many Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

My system has Users, Posts and Categories.

My eloquent relations (omitting the inverses) are as follows:

User `hasMany` posts.
Post `belongsTo` user.
Post `hasOne` category.

I would like to retrieve all the Categories that have been used by a specific User i.e. something along the lines of:

```
$categories = Category->with('posts')
->has('post')
->where('user_id' => $user->id)
->get();
```

Obviously, the above does not work, I merely put it there to present the idea.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your *post* `belongsTo` relation with *category* is named *category* you can do this:

```
$user->load('posts.category');
$user->posts->each(function ($post) {
    $post->category->id;
});
```

**EDIT**

You can add a `hasManyTrough` relation to the **User** model and you'll be able to access all the categories of the user trough the posts. Add to **User** class:

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Category', 'App\Posts');
}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
$user->load('categories');
$categories = $user->categories;
```

This will get all the categories of all the posts that belong to this user.
Note that your model namespace might be different.

Comment: I am trying to avoid the loop to understand the eloquent better since I have a raw mysql solution, I am confident that there must be a eloquent one-liner that gives the desired result

Answer (score 0):

Use nested `whereHas()` and constraining to filter specific user.

```
$categories=Category::whereHas('post.user', function($q) use($id)
{
     $q->where('id',$id);    //constrain on user
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are probably many different ways to achieve what you're after.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through